# iOS - UIWebView not working due to parsing error

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I want to play a Youtube video in my app. So, I wrote the following code

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, videoURL, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height];  

[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

The videoView is a UIWebView. This was working just fine until later, the view shows nothing. Just a blank white view. And I got this log:

```
*** WebKit discarding exception: <NSRangeException> *** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds
```

Comment: I have the same problem using XCode 4.5, iOS 6.0

Comment: Yes. That's also my case, Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6. I am downloading the GM and hope it's a beta issue

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use:

`http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXXX`

instead of:

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXX`

Found here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/705665#705665

Comment: Well, though this is a good solution, it will be hard for me to use. I have a database with over 300 links to youtube videos. Could be something to do with Apple ending the license with Google regarding YouTube?

Comment: Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious!

Answer (score 12):

Maybe my method for translating youtube URL to correct format will help you:

```
+ (NSString*)getYTUrlStr:(NSString*)url
{   
    if (url == nil)
        return nil;

    NSString *retVal = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"watch?v=" withString:@"v/"];

    NSRange pos=[retVal rangeOfString:@"version"];
    if(pos.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        retVal = [retVal stringByAppendingString:@"?version=3&hl=en_EN"];
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue but replacing watch?v by V/ it work fine.

Comment: Its showing the thumbnail in web view with play button over that. On tapping, its playing the video in media player. Not playing as embedded player.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it using the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>\
<html>\
<style>body{padding:0;margin:0;}</style>\
<iframe width=\"320\" height=\"367\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/rVd0XWALswk?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
</html>
```

It has nothing to do with using short URL nor the YouTube URL. It's probably using the embed tag and using the type application/x-shockwave-flash. It's now working perfectly fine on iOS 6 GM.

Comment: thanks to post it, i have your same problem, can you please post the NSString version of that html code? because if i try to use it, give me a warning "Unknown escape sequence \<" thanks!

Comment: You can use the above HTML in NSString as it is. Just don't forget to add @" at the beginning and " at the end of the HTML.

Comment: Great answer! This is the solution I've been looking for iOS6! Combined with the link @Richard provided. I recommend adding the parameter showinfo=0 to the link, to hide the title for a cleaner view inside a UIWebView.

Answer (score -1):

Chances are, with that error, there's an array somewhere that you're going through, but at some point you call some method that ends up trying to reach something that's beyond the array.

For example, code like this would produce an out-of-bounds error:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:objInPositionZero, objInPositionOne, objInPositionTwo, nil];
NSObject *obj;

for (int i=0; i<3, i++)
{
    obj = [array objectAtIndex: (i+6)
}
//Do something with obj.
```

would produce an NSRangeException, because the program is trying to return an item from an index that doesn't actually exist in the array.

So check through all your arrays and make sure that's not happening.