# iOS6 play videos with webView (works in iOS5)

Tags: youtube, ios6

I used to play videos inside my iOS app using uiwebviews with the following code:

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlToOpen, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
self.videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.videoView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:videoView];
[videoView release];
```

With iOS6 it doesn't work.

Has anybody find any solution to play youtube videos compiling with iOS6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Here is the answer.

Use http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXXX

instead of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXX.

find it here:

[iOS - UIWebView not working due to parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399241/ios-uiwebview-not-working-due-to-parsing-error)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with iOS6 Simulator and iOS5 device, if you use the new embed code (iframe) then it works.

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="320" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Only downside is that the iframe contains a lot of dom elements that are downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the follow

```
   NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <iframe title=\"YouTube Video\" class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\"\
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" src=\"%@\"\
    frameborder=\"0\" allowFullScreen ></iframe>";
    NSString *urlToOpen = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?autoplay=1";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlToOpen, frame.size.width,     frame.size.height];
    self.videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.videoView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView release];
```

As Youtube has discard the webview video and introduce iframe so You have to use this html for ios 6 and for ios 5 use the older one.
And remember that your url link for youtube video is should like
http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_Id?autoplay=1
where you can replace video_Id with your own video id.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the embed in Phonegap you have set OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES in Phonegap settings

Answer (score 0):

Youtube with Webviews in iOS6 requires enabled cookies in the WebView. In order to do that, you need to add the following instruction in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
      [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in simulator

[_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/b22cH2sfVcc"]]];

and it works

directly provide the embed src of youtube video to web view and it works.