# video embedded on a link not working on UIWebview with iOS6 simulator or device

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiwebview, ios6

does iOS 6 webview have an issue of presenting videos ? :(

my code is a simple call to webview's loadRequest method:

```
 self.webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WEpUAQ7fa8"]]];
```

cosole says:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Ending background task assertion (8) for playback stall
[MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 1)
```

I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660857/uiwebview-movie-player-getting-dismissed-ios-6-bug) but in vain.

please suggest an answer.

Comment: webview, as already mentioned.

Comment: i have to use webview only, as I am going to use a web page with embedded video.

Comment: @Nikita Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399241/ios-uiwebview-not-working-due-to-parsing-error

Comment: @Nikita youtube page is loading but for playing video you have click on play button in middle

Comment: @DpK No for me its working fine without crash

Comment: exactly, the page obviously opens. but when it tries to get into a full screen, it crashes, and i am left with a webview page with no use.

Comment: @darshana: the link you gave also does not work. Infact I even tried with youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx. nothing works :(

Comment: @darshana but i get the same error as Nikita has mentioned here

Comment: @Nikita Guys in full screen also its not crashing

Comment: @NikitaP same issue happens here too! Don't know how this worked with the other one!

Comment: @darshana: u using a device/simulator? which ios version?

Comment: @darshana can you please list the frameworks  in your project?

Comment: @Dpk UIKit, Foundation,CoreGraphics, SenTesingKit

Comment: @darshana  i get the following crash report"Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'"

Comment: @Dpk Check whether in System Preferences "Sound" setting for input is set to something other than internal mic

Comment: It's not sound, I can hear the sound of the video, even when the video is not playing (the full screen is crashing but the audio is being played)

Comment: @darshana its "No Devices Found " there! i have upgraded my os few days ago, may be due to that

Comment: Hey guys,do you people have QuickTime Player installed on your machines?

Comment: I was hoping you would know that

Comment: @NikitaP join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22175/ios6-webview-issue

Comment: @darshana join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22175/ios6-webview-issue..

Comment: @NikitaP This is working in my iOS6 simulator

Comment: Well, its complicated. I copy-pasted the same code in a new project, its working fine. but in the project i wanna use it, its not working the way it should :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi since you cannot use MPMoviePlayerController, you have to use Webview, instead of using

```
self.webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WEpUAQ7fa8"]]];
```

[Try this way to embed,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117617/embedding-youtube-videos-on-ios)